# Why all invariant factors are 1 if R is a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra

The following includes the definition for invariant factors.

[image]

In other chapter the book says

> In the case where the ring R is a field, the invariant factors are all 1.

I have no clue to prove why that is true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $R = F$ is a field, then $\DeclareMathOperator{\sp}{span} \sp_F(sx) = \sp_F(x)$ for any nonzero $s \in F$, since we can simply multiply by $1/s$.  In other words, if $\{s_1 x_1, \ldots, s_n x_n\}$ is a basis of $N$, then so is $\{x_1, \ldots, x_n\}$.  Thus we can take all the $s_i$ to be $1$.